# PHP Creating an indexed array vs associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am calling the getTeams function below to get a simple list of team names but I can't get it to work without a 2 step process.
If I use

```
function getTeams($teams){
      
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
         $team = $team['team'];
         $teamNames[] = $team['displayName'];            
    }
    return $teamNames;      
}
```

It looks like it is creating an associative array with the keys being numeric starting at 0?

I can make it work using

```
function getTeams($teams){
      
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
         $team = $team['team'];
         $teamNames[] = $team['displayName'];        
    }
    
    for ($i= 0; $i < count($teamNames); $i++){
        $teamNames2[$teamNames[$i]]=$teamNames[$i]; 
    }
    return $teamNames2;
        
}
```

I think it might be because the first array is an associative Array and the second one is creating an indexed array? Is that thought process correct? If so, what is the correct way to create an indexed array in the foreach loop?

Comment: This code `$teamNames[] = ...` itself always created indexed array **not** associative array. But the value in `$team['displayName'];` can be associative array.

Comment: You want something like : `['team1'=>'team1','team2'=>'team2',..]`? Could you post a short part of `$teams`?

Comment: I have it confused after looking at it, the foreach returns an array in this format  array(32) { [0]=> string(17) "Arizona Cardinals" [1]=> string(15) "Atlanta Falcons" [2]=> string(16) "Baltimore Ravens" which is looks like an indexed array.
The for loop returns it in this format
array(32) { ["Arizona Cardinals"]=> string(17) "Arizona Cardinals" ["Atlanta Falcons"]=> string(15) "Atlanta Falcons" ["Baltimore Ravens"]=> string(16) "Baltimore Ravens" ["Buffalo Bills"]=> string(13) "Buffalo Bills"
Which is an associative one... So I need to make the foreach loop create an associative array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your array: If you want to create an associative array you should give its element a key. So instead of

```
function getTeams($teams){
      
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
         $team = $team['team'];
         $teamNames[] = $team['displayName'];            
    }
    return $teamNames;      
}
```

where the code

```
$teamNames[]
```

will add always an **indexed** entry to your array.

If you want a associative entry use a key instead. Something like

```
function getTeams($teams){

    foreach ($teams as $team) {
         $team = $team['team'];
         $teamNames[$team['key']] = $team['displayName'];            
    }
    return $teamNames;      
}
```

`$teamNames` should now return an associative array

Comment: The array created in the foreach loop returns this from var_dump

array(32) { [0]=> string(17) "Arizona Cardinals" [1]=> string(15) "Atlanta Falcons" [2]=> string(16) "Baltimore Ravens" [3]=> string(13) "Buffalo Bills" [4]=> string(17)

And the array from the for loop returns 

array(32) { ["Arizona Cardinals"]=> string(17) "Arizona Cardinals" ["Atlanta Falcons"]=> string(15) "Atlanta Falcons" ["Baltimore Ravens"]=> string(16) "Baltimore Ravens" ["Buffalo Bills"]=> string(13) "Buffalo Bills" ["Carolina Panthers"]=> string(17)

How do I get the foreach loop to return the same array?

Comment: What is the value of `$team['key']` ?

Comment: `$team['key']` was just a wild guess, don't know if this exists on your side. Try `$team['displayName']`, this should definetely give you an associative array even if it makes not much sense

Comment: Changing it to $team['displayName'] worked